# Aligning ggplot facets in a patchworked graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I have graph consisting of several `ggplots` combined using `patchwork`. I have made a `ggplot` only consisting of the y-axis. This works fine, but the facets are not aligned above each. Any ideas as how to make the facets have the same size and be above each other?

[image]

Here's the patchwork code:

```
y_axis + decreasers_p+late_bloomers_p + o2_lovers_p + solo_riders_p + plot_layout(widths = c(1, 10), 
                                                                        guides = "collect",
                                                                        design = 
                                                                        "12
                                                                         13
                                                                         14
                                                                         15")
```

And here's some of the ggplot code:

```
solo_riders_p <- ggplot(solo_riders, aes(x=days_incubated, y=emission))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=compound, size=compound, fill=compound)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 25))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(2.8, 2.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "grey"))+
  labs(fill = "Compound", shape = "Compound", size = "Compound", 
       x = "Incubation time (days)", 
       y = "BVOC emission (nmol g-1 loi soil h-1)", 
       title = "solo_riders") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(jar), scales = "free_y")

y_axis <- ggplot(data.frame(l = decreasers_p$labels$y, x = 1, y = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = l), angle = 90) + 
  theme_void() +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

Here's an example of how I would like it to be (but without the titles above each row):

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate to the question you asked 4 minutes prior to this one. Any differences? If not, please remove this. If yes, please make these differences apparent in the text of your questions.

Comment: Pretty sure the alignment is off due to the widths of the y-axis text labels at the ticks, I wouldn't know how to fix it though.

Comment: @Imo, it's the same data and code but the questions are different. Here I ask about how to allign facets of the ggplots and in the other I ask how to move the y-axis closer to the ggplots.